# Trigger for one off workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I have been using Power Automate to create some workflows for a SharePoint list. There are a series of emails which get sent to different users as the Status column is changed - this is triggered when an item is created or modified it checks the status and sends an email as appropriate.

This works fine since it is a linear process where a user does their task and then changes the status.

However there is one field that will be activated at some point through the process and will stay constant through a number of the different statuses.

Is there some way we can have a field that just triggers the workflow the first time that value is selected. Otherwise it will be sending duplicate emails every time the item is modified and that field remains selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow has a newish action called "get changes for an item or a file", which allows you to determine which column changed. [Here](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/run-a-flow-when-a-sharepoint-column-is-modified/) is the blog post introducing the action, and there is also a video showing usage.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mike2500, you can use "**Get changes on an item or a file (property only)**" actionn to achieve your needs. You can rely on this action to determine which column is changed.

**Here is a good case for your reference:**

- [How to use Get changes on an item or a file (property only)
  action?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-use-Get-changes-on-an-item-or-a-file-property-only-action/td-p/659336)